# Is it possible to get username from AppConnect MobileIron Sdk?

Tags: ios, xcode, mdm

I am working on mdm systems and i need get username that logged in to MobileIron from device is it possible to get user informations from MobileIron ios lib AppConnect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to provide an app configuration file using the MobileIron interface.

1) Login into the MobileIron backend
2) Select "Policies & Configs"
3) "Add New" > "Managed App Config"
4) Edit the settings and select the app you target for
5) In the section "App-specific Configurations" add the key `user` with the value `$USERID$`

You should now get the user id of the logged in user by using the dictionary.

`// Objective-C (iOS)
NSString *userID = [[AppConnect sharedInstance] config] valueForKey:@"user"];`